# How do I stop a PayPal transaction from inside the IPN?

Tags: php, paypal, payment-processing, paypal-ipn

I want to be able to stop a transaction if the details that I am checking are incorrect.

An example of my code

```
// check that receiver_email is your Primary PayPal email
if($_POST['receiver_email'] != "my_email@mail.co.uk") {
exit(); // exit script
}
```

I use `exit()` but while testing this using `sandbox.paypal.com` when the email is incorrect and `exit()` is called the transaction still processes and in essence gives the sandbox account the money.

Comment: I'm not an expert, but I don't think you can stop the transaction at all. IPN means instant payment *notification*, meaning the transaction has already happened

Comment: Usually what it reaches your IPN, it's likely *already been processed*, unless it was an eCheck or something. It's not a notification of "this transaction has been started," it's a "you have received money for this transaction."

Comment: @animuson that is a fair point, but my IPN also checks the _POST data with that of what is stored in my database. So if someone tried to do some price-jacking on my site it would been checked here. So it would make sense to not accept the payment.

Comment: You can't do that with IPN. IPN is simply a notification you receive from PayPal. While you can check the data against your own, IPN gives you no facility to programatically stop a transaction.

Comment: Probably, and to stop price jacking use encrypted buttons.

Comment: You're all wrong. This is possible with IPN. The fact that you get a notification, doesn't mean you can't programmatically call an API to deal with this. You can. The only thing that would prevent you from doing what you want to accomplish is that you can't stop someone else's transaction. In other words; if the receiver_email is not an email adddress listed on your account, the transaction thus doesn't 'belong to your account', and as such your account is not able to do anything with this transaction. You would just need to discard the message and set the order state to 'Invalid' or 'Pending'

Comment: However, if your example would be, for instance, if $amountpaid < $_POST['mc_gross'], you could easily call the RefundTransaction API to automatically refund the transaction -- I'll add a detailed answer incl. some sample code in a few hours.

Comment: @Robert okay thanks, I would need to look into what happens with an invalid IPN. The business may receive the money but will PayPal automatically revoke this at a later date?

Comment: `INVALID` is only returned if it's not a genuine transaction (aside from any encoding issues that may potentially cause validation to fail.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned, this is certainly possible. Ideally, you would want to offload any processing from your IPN handler so that the IPN handler can focus on receiving POST data from PayPal.
But you can use the following to check the paid amount matches the amount expected, and automatically refund if the amount differs.

For example (based on the PayPal PHP sample code, and quickly thrown together).
Note: This code merely serves to illustrate the logic behind this.

```
<?php

// Set this dynamically.
$amountToBeExpected = "0.99";


// PHP 4.1

// read the post from PayPal system and add 'cmd'
$req = 'cmd=_notify-validate';

foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
$value = urlencode(stripslashes($value));
$req .= "&$key=$value";
}

// post back to PayPal system to validate
$header .= "POST /cgi-bin/webscr HTTP/1.0\r\n";
$header .= "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n";
$header .= "Content-Length: " . strlen($req) . "\r\n\r\n";
$fp = fsockopen ('ssl://www.paypal.com', 443, $errno, $errstr, 30);

// assign posted variables to local variables
$item_name = $_POST['item_name'];
$item_number = $_POST['item_number'];
$payment_status = $_POST['payment_status'];
$payment_amount = $_POST['mc_gross'];
$payment_currency = $_POST['mc_currency'];
$txn_id = $_POST['txn_id'];
$receiver_email = $_POST['receiver_email'];
$payer_email = $_POST['payer_email'];

if (!$fp) {
// HTTP ERROR
} else {
fputs ($fp, $header . $req);
while (!feof($fp)) {
$res = fgets ($fp, 1024);
if (strcmp ($res, "VERIFIED") == 0) {
// check the payment_status is Completed
// check that txn_id has not been previously processed
// check that receiver_email is your Primary PayPal email
// check that payment_amount/payment_currency are correct
// process payment


    if($payment_amount != $amountToBeExpected) {
        /** RefundTransaction NVP example; last modified 08MAY23.
         *
         *  Issue a refund for a prior transaction. 
        */

        $environment = 'sandbox';   // or 'beta-sandbox' or 'live'

        /**
         * Send HTTP POST Request
         *
         * @param   string  The API method name
         * @param   string  The POST Message fields in &name=value pair format
         * @return  array   Parsed HTTP Response body
         */
        function PPHttpPost($methodName_, $nvpStr_) {
            global $environment;

            // Set up your API credentials, PayPal end point, and API version.
            $API_UserName = urlencode('my_api_username');
            $API_Password = urlencode('my_api_password');
            $API_Signature = urlencode('my_api_signature');
            $API_Endpoint = "https://api-3t.paypal.com/nvp";
            if("sandbox" === $environment || "beta-sandbox" === $environment) {
                $API_Endpoint = "https://api-3t.$environment.paypal.com/nvp";
            }
            $version = urlencode('51.0');

            // Set the curl parameters.
            $ch = curl_init();
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $API_Endpoint);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);

            // Turn off the server and peer verification (TrustManager Concept).
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, FALSE);

            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);

            // Set the API operation, version, and API signature in the request.
            $nvpreq = "METHOD=$methodName_&VERSION=$version&PWD=$API_Password&USER=$API_UserName&SIGNATURE=$API_Signature$nvpStr_";

            // Set the request as a POST FIELD for curl.
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $nvpreq);

            // Get response from the server.
            $httpResponse = curl_exec($ch);

            if(!$httpResponse) {
                exit("$methodName_ failed: ".curl_error($ch).'('.curl_errno($ch).')');
            }

            // Extract the response details.
            $httpResponseAr = explode("&", $httpResponse);

            $httpParsedResponseAr = array();
            foreach ($httpResponseAr as $i => $value) {
                $tmpAr = explode("=", $value);
                if(sizeof($tmpAr) > 1) {
                    $httpParsedResponseAr[$tmpAr[0]] = $tmpAr[1];
                }
            }

            if((0 == sizeof($httpParsedResponseAr)) || !array_key_exists('ACK', $httpParsedResponseAr)) {
                exit("Invalid HTTP Response for POST request($nvpreq) to $API_Endpoint.");
            }

            return $httpParsedResponseAr;
        }

        // Set request-specific fields.
        $transactionID = urlencode($txn_id);
        $refundType = urlencode('Full');                        // or 'Partial'
        //$amount;                                              // required if Partial.
        //$memo;                                                    // required if Partial.
        $currencyID = urlencode('USD');                         // or other currency ('GBP', 'EUR', 'JPY', 'CAD', 'AUD')

        // Add request-specific fields to the request string.
        $nvpStr = "&TRANSACTIONID=$transactionID&REFUNDTYPE=$refundType&CURRENCYCODE=$currencyID";

        if(isset($memo)) {
            $nvpStr .= "&NOTE=$memo";
        }

        if(strcasecmp($refundType, 'Partial') == 0) {
            if(!isset($amount)) {
                exit('Partial Refund Amount is not specified.');
            } else {
                $nvpStr = $nvpStr."&AMT=$amount";
            }

            if(!isset($memo)) {
                exit('Partial Refund Memo is not specified.');
            }
        }

        // Execute the API operation; see the PPHttpPost function above.
        $httpParsedResponseAr = PPHttpPost('RefundTransaction', $nvpStr);

        if("SUCCESS" == strtoupper($httpParsedResponseAr["ACK"]) || "SUCCESSWITHWARNING" == strtoupper($httpParsedResponseAr["ACK"])) {
            exit('Refund Completed Successfully: '.print_r($httpParsedResponseAr, true));
        } else  {
            exit('RefundTransaction failed: ' . print_r($httpParsedResponseAr, true));
        }



    }



}
else if (strcmp ($res, "INVALID") == 0) {

}
}
fclose ($fp);
}
?>
```